# Why is MySQL not using indexes with composite WHERE IN?

Tags: mysql, indexing, composite-key, query-performance, where-in

I am trying to get several records by composite index from a table having PRIMARY KEY (a, b)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a, b) IN ((1,2), (2,4), (1,3))
```

The problem is, that MySQL is not using index, even if I FORCE INDEX (`PRIMARY`).
EXPLAIN SELECT shows null possible_keys.

Why there are no possible_keys?

What is the best way to retrieve multiple rows by composite key:

- using OR
- using UNION ALL
- using WHERE () IN ((),())

P.S. Query is equal by result to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a = 1 AND b = 2) OR (a = 2 AND b = 4) OR (a = 1 AND b = 3)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If query selects only fields from index (or if table has no other fields) by composite `WHERE ... IN`, index will be used:

```
SELECT a,b FROM `table` WHERE (a, b) IN ((1,2), (2,4), (1,3))
```

Otherwise it will not be used. 
The workaround is to use derived query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT a, b FROM `table` WHERE (a, b) IN ((1,2), (2,4), (1,3))) AS o INNER JOIN `table` AS t ON (t.a = o.a AND t.b = o.b)
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2   
1   PRIMARY t   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   o.a,o.b 1   
2   DERIVED table   index   NULL    PRIMARY 2   NULL    6   Using where; Using index
```

Answer (score 0):

In strong desire of indexing a certain column, have you considered having a new column: `a_b` which is basicly `CONCAT(a, '-', b)` and just compare that (`WHERE a_b = {$id1}-{$id2}`)?

And you can only have one PRIMARY column per table. You can't "index primary" both `a` and `b`

Comment: Using `CONCAT(a, '-', b)` is not a good option for me, as it can fail if I have `'-'` in field value. 
My PRIMARY KEY is multicolumn, so it contains both `a` and `b`.

Comment: `CONCAT(a, '!-!', b)` - do you ever use that value? :)

Comment: My table contains hundreds of millions of records, I don't think  indexed string column would increase performance. I'd rather go with UNION ALL for batch composite select.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the combined index on the columns a,b.

Index doesn't need to be primary key and it can still help a lot.

More info about your issue here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html